# Pass custom property values to Open Graph Object in native Android app with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, properties, sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am creating my own native Android App with Facebook integration to publish open graph stories.

The publishing works fine, but I want to include a custom string property (wishdesc) (which the user provided inside the app) inside the story post (e.g. description).

How can I do that? I tried this, before my object/action gets published in an AsyncTask given by Facebook, bot none of them work.

```
    MakeAction makeAction = action.cast(MakeAction.class);

    makeAction.setProperty("wishdesc", "###MY NEW DESC");
    makeAction.setProperty("wish.wishdesc", "###MY NEW DESC");
    makeAction.setProperty("muku-starcall:wishdesc", "###MY NEW DESC");

    WishGraphObject wishToBe = null;
    wishToBe = WishGraphObject.Factory.create(WishGraphObject.class);
    wishToBe.setProperty("muku-starcall:wishdesc", "###MY NEW DESC");
    wishToBe.setProperty("wish.wishdesc", "###MY NEW DESC");

    ...
```

Comment: Is the "wishdesc" defined on your OG object or OG action?

Comment: it is on the OG object.

i now have tried this:
i have given the ACTION an additional custom property, and set that property via "setProperty" like above, and it works. it doesn't seem to work for an object though, only for an action.

if I give the OBJECT an additional property via app dashboard, do I need to list that property in the OBJECT html file too?

Comment: Yes, if you're using the html method for objects, the extra fields have to be in the html file as well (since the html file represents a single object).